# Why is the UDP client not able to receive the message?

Tags: python-3.x, sockets, udp

Just a beginner here. The client sends a message to the server using `sendto()`, which the server is able to receive using `recvfrom()`. The problem occurs when the server then tries to send a message to the client. The client code gets stuck on `indata, add = sock.recvfrom(1024)`. Why exactly is this happening?

SERVER CODE:

```
import socket
port = 8000
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
address = ('127.0.0.1',port)
try:
    s.bind(address)
except socket.error as e:
    print(e)
while True:
    data, add = s.recvfrom(1024)
    break
print(data.decode(), add)


fin = open("send.txt")
senddata = fin.read()
print(senddata)
try:
    s.sendto(senddata.encode(),address)
except socket.error as e:
    print(e)
s.close()
```

CLIENT CODE:

```
import socket

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_DGRAM)

port = 8000
msg = 'hello server'

sock.sendto(msg.encode(),('127.0.0.1',port))

while True:
    indata, add = sock.recvfrom(1024)
    break
f = open("received.txt", 'w')
f.write(indata.decode())
sock.close()
```

Should multiple ports be used if both the client and server are being run on the same machine?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is here:

```
s.sendto(senddata.encode(),address)
```

... `address` in this case is the server's address, so the server is sending the packet back to itself, rather than to the client.  When I changed the above to:

```
s.sendto(senddata.encode(),add)
```

... the program worked as intended.  (There's probably an argument to be made for more descriptive variable names, e.g. `clientAddress` and `serverAddress`, to avoid this sort of confusion)

> Should multiple ports be used if both the client and server are being
>   run on the same machine?

Yes, and in fact your code is using multiple ports.  In particular, your server binds its socket to port 8000, and your client (implicitly) binds its socket to some other port-number (since you never explicitly call `bind()` on the client socket, which is fine for this use-case).

Answer (score 0):

The server binds to port 8000 in your code. The client gets an arbitrary port number (no bind used).  When the server sends to port 8000, it's sending to itself.

You need two ports and the server needs to know what the client is using.  The recvfrom call in the server should be able to tell you the remote port number (but I am not familiar with the Python socket API so cannot tell you how).